# AngularJS Protractor and Socket.IO

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io, protractor

When setting up an E2E test with my existing angular app, I am having trouble getting starting since I am using socket.io in my application. Protractor can't find the socket.io files that are typically served by the node module since it's not part of my personal code.

I am getting the error:

```
UnknownError: Error Message => 'Can't find variable: io'
```

On the angular side:

```
angular.module('socket.io', []).factory(function($rootScope) {
  var socket = io.connect(); // I believe the error is being thrown from here
  return {
    on: function (eventName, callback) {
      socket.on(eventName, function () {...});
    },
    emit: function (eventName, data, callback) {
      socket.emit(eventName, data, function () {...});
    }
  };
});
```

I believe that is because it's typically served by the node module:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
```

vs my socket.io factory shown above

```
<script type="text/javascript" src='js/services/socket-service.js'></script>
```

Is there a way to solve this without having the copy the socket.io.js file in to the client codebase?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the file `socket.io.js` is being included before `socket-service.js`.  You can either do thus manually or use a module loader such as requirejs (http://www.requirejs.org)

Comment: That's a good point, however I don't think that is the issue. I do have me loading the socket.io.js file before it gets referenced by my socket-service.js. If I copy the socket.io.js file out of node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js and in to where my client files are stored (and reference it appropriately), everything works. I just didn't want to have to do this step.